# (Why) did the Buddha teach rebirth?

Tags: rebirth

1. Was rebirth introduced in the First or Second Turnings, and why did the Buddha teach it? E.g. was it necessary to understand emptiness, causality, etc.? 
   For example, I imagine that some "reasons why" might include:

   - Maybe it helps deemphasize a person's current lifetime, highlighting its impermanence, so that one does not cling to it or themselves.
   - On the other hand, for some, it seems to be a source of inspiration to persevere on the Path, for a "good rebirth".
2. Would any of the Buddhist doctrines, excluding karma and rebirth, fail to make sense without rebirth?

Comment: The Buddha taught only facts and fundamental concepts, i.e. Re-birth.  Could you give some examples where avoiding the teaching/concept of rebirth make more sense in certain doctrines?

Comment: There must be a bunch of questions on this already... Did you search?

Comment: It appears rebirth has been discussed at length on [tricycle](https://tricycle.org/trikedaily/rebirth-debate/), however, many of the links are dead.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov searched before, but did not find any answers to the question on why rebirth was taught by the Buddha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Buddha taught karma and rebirth under *mundane right view* -

> *Right view, I say, is twofold: there is right view that is affected by influxes, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions; and there is right view that is noble, free of influxes, supramundane, a factor of the path.*
>
> [AN 6.63](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.063.than.html)

and as Bhikku Bodhi goes on to write in [The Buddha's Teachings on Social and Communal Harmony](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01G2DD5QY)

> “Right view affected by influxes” implies that even as we attempt to see and act in accord with the Dharma, we are still affected by the **delusion of self**. “Partaking of merit” is using Buddhist practice for what we perceive as our own benefit. “Ripening in the acquisitions” means becoming or **acquiring a self**. These are mundane or worldly ways.

Since this *mundane right view* is still "affected by influxes", with notions of self, not only is rebirth unnecessary to understand not-self, it may in fact be incompatible, as further explained in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19773/8619).

This may be why the Buddha taught  *superior right view*. It is this right view which leads to liberation, as [Bhikku Bodhi writes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007626M3E) -

> This **superior right view** leading to liberation is the understanding of the Four Noble Truths. It is this right view that figures as the first factor of the Noble Eightfold Path in the proper sense: as the noble right view. Thus the Buddha defines the path factor of right view expressly in terms of the four truths: “What now is right view? It is understanding of suffering (dukkha), understanding of the origin of suffering, understanding of the cessation of suffering, understanding of the way leading to the cessation of suffering

Belief in rebirth (as reincarnation) is also unnecessary in regards to ethics and morality, as [Bhikku Bodhi further writes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01G2DD5QY) -

> Several texts testify that the Buddha himself seems to have recognized that morality can be established on the basis of self- reflection and ethical reasoning without requiring a belief in personal survival of death.

Answer (score 5):

The [Truth of Rebirth](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/truth_of_rebirth.html) seems to be one of the larger points of dispute between participants on this site. See [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/dharma-without-karma) and [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/is-rebirth-a-delusional-belief) for similar questions and answers. I guess this is not all that surprising to me since the site seems heavily represented by Western practitioners. In my experience it seems that westerners have (*and I definitely include myself here*) a particularly difficult time with the Truth of Rebirth as taught by the Buddha. Here is what [Venerable Thanissaro Bhikkhu has to say about this:](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/truth_of_rebirth.html)

> Yet as these Buddhist religions have come to the West, they have run
> into a barrier from modern Western culture: Of all the Buddha's
> teachings, rebirth has been one of the hardest for modern Westerners
> to accept. Part of this resistance comes from the fact that none of
> the dominant world-views of Western culture, religious or
> materialistic, contain anything corresponding to the idea of repeated
> rebirth. Plato taught it, but — aside from an esoteric fringe — few in
> the modern West have treated this side of his teaching as anything
> more than a myth.
>
> For people who have felt burned or repelled by the faith demands of
> Western religion, there is the added barrier that the teaching on
> rebirth is something that — for the unawakened — has to be taken on
> faith. They would prefer a Buddhism that makes no faith demands,
> focusing its attention solely on the benefits it can bring in this
> life.

There seem to be many approaches on this site:

1. Simply denying outright that the Buddha taught rebirth.
2. The Buddha taught the reality of rebirth as a (re)birth that takes place in this very life whenever self-views of "I" and "mine" occur. No "afterlife" concept of rebirth was taught or acknowledged by the Buddha.
3. Admitting he taught it, but insisting it was just skillful means.
4. Rebirth as a *combination* of metaphor and [upaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upaya).
5. Those who take rebirth at face value, but insist that mere experience can end.
6. Like above, but do not posit an end to this mere experience.
7. Those who think rebirth (generally) can be known incontrovertibly through reason alone.
8. Those who think rebirth requires a dose of faith to be known (generally).

And probably a number of other views that I've missed. Myself, I'm with 6 and 7.

**Was rebirth introduced in the First or Second Turnings, and why did the Buddha teach it?**

To my mind, *unquestionably* it was taught and introduced. I think the Buddha taught it because it was/is a conventional truth and the Buddha taught the truth.

**Would any of the Buddhist doctrines, excluding karma and rebirth, fail to make sense without rebirth?**

Yes, I think there are obvious logical problems and inconsistencies that present if you deny the truth of rebirth. For instance, as BodhiWalker mentions above one could seek the end of suffering by merely ending this current life. Even more problematic, one could "liberate" others from suffering by murdering sentient beings painlessly. That's monstrous and I want nothing to do with it. I want to make quite clear, I'm sure *this is not what others have in mind* when denying or glossing the truth of rebirth. I'm emphatically not concluding that those who deny or gloss the truth of rebirth are murderous monsters, just that denying or glossing the truth of rebirth presents logical problems that I don't see a way around.

Anyway, I think Venerable Thanissaro Bhikkhu's article above is excellent and highly recommend reading it many times and contemplating these questions.

Comment: I scored this answer down because it did not once mention the reality of rebirth.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu can you explain what you mean by "the reality of rebirth?" I really would like to understand what you are saying

Comment: What kind of edit would you suggest to the answer to improve it?

Comment: The answer neglected the 're-birth' the Buddha taught, which is the production of self-views that give birth to the idea of self; as described in many suttas, such as SN 22.81, which says: "The uninstructed assumes form, feeling, perception, formations, consciousness to be self. That assumption is a fabrication. Now what is the cause, what is the origination, what is the birth, what is the coming-into-existence of that fabrication? To an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person, touched by that which is felt born of contact with ignorance, craving arises. That fabrication is born of that. "

Comment: Ok, i will try to reflect this understanding in my list and edit it to be clear that the part about westerners is my only reflective of my own experience/opinion. Do you regard the Buddha teaching about the knowledge he gained of his past lives during his night of awakening as similar descriptions of self-views that took place in Siddhartha's regular mortal life? I only ask as a point of clarification and not to try and challenge your understanding...

Comment: Your patience is excellent. Well done! As for the Buddha, he did not experience any "past lives", as confirmed by this proper translation of SN 22.79: https://suttacentral.net/sn22.79/en/bodhi Regards

Comment: @Dhammadhatu I was referring to  https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.036.than.html where it is quoted as, "I directed it to the knowledge of recollecting my past lives. I recollected my manifold past lives, i.e., one birth, two...five, ten...fifty, a hundred, a thousand, a hundred thousand, many eons of cosmic contraction, many eons of cosmic expansion, many eons of cosmic contraction & expansion" ... what is your understanding of this sutta?

Comment: @YesheTenley Indeed. Dhammadhatu points to "[pubbenivāsa](https://suttacentral.net/define/pubbeniv%C4%81sa)" which is used in that phrase, and says that should be translated as "past abodes" rather than like "past lives", and that it's about self-views. One of his habits on this site is to say so, whenever the topic of rebirth comes up, and to downvote every answer which doesn't say the same. See also [these topics](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Newest&q=user%3a8157%20rebirth), and/or he recommended [this essay](https://www.buddhismwithoutboundaries.com/Anatta_and_Rebirth.pdf).

Comment: Ok, I've edited #2 to reflect this understanding as best I'm capable.

Comment: @YesheTenley `I think there are obvious logical problems and inconsistencies that present if you deny the truth of rebirth. ...` Those hypothetical problems that follow, to my knowledge, weren't addressed by the word of the Buddha, nor do I know if they are even fundamental enough to ponder. My concern is more with how would the core teachings e.g. 4 Noble Truths, Emptiness, or Causality, fail to make sense without belief in rebirth.

Comment: @YesheTenley thank you for your generous answer and directing me to the article. It may answer my questions. What concerns me, is that something is repeated so many times that one believes it without question, and may argue from a place that already assumes it to be true.

Comment: He says `You take these matters on faith until you can confirm them for yourself.` which troubles me. [Faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faith_in_Buddhism#Through_verification) in Buddhism as I understand it, *is* confirming things for yourself before you believe them.

Comment: @avatarKorra You might ask a separate question. Currently you're asking, "how (if it all) does rebirth (or a lack of faith in rebirth) affect one's understanding of the three characteristics?" A slightly separate question (but which might be closer to the question you want to ask) is, "Is it possible to understand and benefit from the doctrine of the three characteristics, without holding a belief in rebirth?" I guess the answers are, "Yes, faith in rebirth has some effects on the doctrines, *and*, yes it's possible to (many people do) also make sense of the doctrine even without that belief."

Comment: @avatarKorra Perhaps you should rewind your edit of this question as ChrisW has said and ask a separate question so that people are not confused when visiting this OP and seeing the questions/answers not align...

Comment: @ChrisW what you said about asking a separate question makes sense.

Comment: Pertinent to this answer, though, [apparently](http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/articles/should-i-believe-in-rebirth/) there are Buddhist traditions (e.g. Zen per the link) that do not require a belief in rebirth, so presumably these traditions do not see any logical inconsistencies. That Buddhism can still have its soteriological effects, both with and without a belief in rebirth IMHO makes it all the more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of rebirth is an axiomatic corolary of 'Karma'.

Also if rebirth does not exist then *nibbana* i.e. 'blowing out' doesn't make sense.

For e.g. without rebirth and without afterlife in heaven or hell you will be  essentially 'blown out' *nibbanafied* without doing anything.

So *nibbana* makes sense only because rebirth exist, because in rebirth the flame continues.

Also, murdering sentient beings (in a painless way) would also be equivalent to liberating them from suffering if rebirth does not exist.

So it is a pretty central doctrine, even if you don't emphasize on Karma.

Comment: Not really. If you get born in another realm due to your bad deeds in this life, then it makes sense to "strive" for nibbana. The 4 noble truths do not mention rebirth at all (nor does the noble eightfold path), but just that suffering exists and that it can be ceased. Now the 4 Noble Truths are higher teachings and most people I would assume haven't realized them..

Comment: @Val sorry i dont see exactly wherr are you contradicting my point. Yes it makes sense to strive for nirvana only because u are reborn in another realm. Also 4 noble truth and 8 fold path dont mention rebirth but they lead us to understanding of Karma through 'right action' and Rebirth is just extension of Karma.

Comment: @Val I would dispute that the Buddha did not teach rebirth or karma when he taught the 4NT. Both are implicit in dependent origination. See here: [The Noble Truth of Rebirth](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/truth_of_rebirth.html#noble)

Comment: @BodhiWalker you could even add that murdering sentient beings (in a painless way) would also be equivalent to liberating them from suffering if rebirth does not exist

Comment: @YesheTenley okies added.

Comment: @BodhiWalker `For e.g. without rebirth and without afterlife in heaven or hell you will be essentially 'blown out' nibbanafied without doing anything.` doesn't causality and impermanence teach us that all composite phenomena, e.g. a house or a person, will eventually cease to exist without "doing anything" because it is by nature, impermanent?

Comment: @avatarKorra  impermenance more of implies the inherent 'change' in nature of composite phenomena...a person will cease to exist in the form he is in, which is infact happening every moment he is there...so when his body ceases in death that is not 'nibbana'...his energy survives in material and non-material form...ofcourse he no longer identifies with pervious self.

Comment: There are Buddhist traditions that do not require belief in rebirth. So Nibbana apparently makes sense. See [this article](http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/articles/should-i-believe-in-rebirth/).

Comment: @avatarKorra Which Buddhist traditions are you talking about?

Comment: @BodhiWalker - Gil Fronsdal, the author of [the article](http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/articles/should-i-believe-in-rebirth/) says, "I have practiced in particular Buddhist traditions that do not require a belief in rebirth", then says Zen. 
A faith in the Buddha's teachings such that the rest of the teachings no longer stand as truth without the promise of rebirth just seems very weak.

Comment: @avatarKorra faith in rebirth is not imperative to either practise or attaining Nibbana. IMO selective acceptance of Buddhas words to fit your own world view shows weak faith. My argument in the answer is not that Nibbana can be attained only with belief in rebirth, it that the whole doctrine has meaning only in context of rebirth.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the Buddha taught that it was necessary to assume rebirth.
Take this from the Kalama Sutta:

> "'Suppose there is a hereafter and there is a fruit, result, of deeds
>   done well or ill. Then it is possible that at the dissolution of the
>   body after death, I shall arise in the heavenly world, which is
>   possessed of the state of bliss.' This is the first solace found by
>   him.
>
> "'Suppose there is no hereafter and there is no fruit, no result, of
>   deeds done well or ill. Yet in this world, here and now, free from
>   hatred, free from malice, safe and sound, and happy, I keep myself.'
>   This is the second solace found by him.

Clearly, any of the meditative practices the Buddha taught focus attention on the rebirth that happens in this moment, here and now.

Answer (score 1):

**Was rebirth introduced in the First or Second Turnings, and why did the Buddha teach it?**

I think the idea of rebirth preceded (predated, already existed earlier than) the Buddha's doctrine:

> [Early Hinduism, Jainism and Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reincarnation#Early_Hinduism,_Jainism_and_Buddhism)
>
> The idea of reincarnation has early roots in the Vedic period (c. 1500 – c. 500 BCE), predating the Buddha and the Mahavira.

I think that, therefore, the question[s] which the Buddhist doctrine had to answer included, "Is the 'rebirth' doctrine true, to what extent is it true (how does it fit with other Buddhist doctrines), what does it mean exactly, how does it work, what is kamma?" and similar questions.

**Would any of the Buddhist doctrines, excluding karma and rebirth, fail to make sense without rebirth?**

I don't know, maybe some of these might be affected:

- [Stages of enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment) -- that perhaps you won't be enlightened in this life, but even so that's not too late (and that effort is always even though immediate result may seem impossible)
- An incentive (albeit "siding with merit and resulting in acquisition") for morality: including, both, generosity and harmlessness
- The concept of [merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merit_(Buddhism)) may affect the relationship between lay society and the sangha
- The three characteristics:

  - *anatta* e.g. as explained in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26364/254) -- if rebirth doesn't exist, does that mean that we live and die, and if so isn't that identifying with the aggregates?
  - *anicca* -- so you're saying that death is permanent, not impermanent?
  - *dukkha* -- without the doctrine of rebirth, some people may develop strange or wrong ideas around killing or suicide as being an escape from dukkha ... also the doctrine that "craving to live (or, for becoming)" and "craving to die (or, for cessation)" are, both, forms of craving
- The superiority (super-humanity) of the Buddha (not according to the suttas, necessarily, but e.g. the Jataka tales and the Mahāvaṃsa)
- Combining cyclic cosmology with the dhamma's being timeless (previous and future Buddhas)
- Atheism -- no sense in worshipping the Gods too much, they too are subject to rebirth
- Hope or optimism -- no matter how bad things seem now, etc.
- Some sense in which dhamma is called timeless (*akalika*)

Comment: What do you mean by “hope or optimism”? The doctrine of rebirth seems much more pessimistic than materialism – there needs to be a lot of effort over numerous lives to achieve something that a materialist takes for granted as happening at the end of every single life.

Comment: More opportunities for a precious human birth in which to be fortunate, to hear the dhamma, to make some progress towards enlightenment, to help ... and more scope for agency (as opposed to e.g. helplessness) e.g. no "we are all predestined to die, so nothing we can do matters".

Comment: Other people might hope that their deceased beloved might have a favourable rebirth. Not everyone sees rebirth, or life, as nothing but a disaster (to be pessimistic of), even if that is one of the messages in the suttas.

Answer (score 0):

**First Noble Truth**: **saṃkhittena pañc·upādāna·k·khandhā dukkhā** - In short, the five aggregates of clinging is suffering.

If all mental activities cease at death, there will be no craving after death as it is clearly a mental activity. If that's the case, apart from craving, **the second noble truth** should include things like breathing, eating, drinking, checking for vehicles before crossing the road and pretty much anything else that keeps you alive.

**The third noble truth**(s) would be both Nibbana and death.

Apart from the noble eightfold path that one needs to practice with years of dedication, **the fourth noble truth**(s) would include hanging yourself, shooting yourself, drowning, starving to death, death by lethal injection, sleeping on a railway, jumping from a skyscraper or **pretty much doing whatever you like until you end up dead**.

Imagine a criminal with such a belief saying **"I became a serial killer so the government would make me enlightened by capital punishment."**

Such a religion would mainly provide laughter to people instead of being taken seriously. :)

Comment: Maybe the Buddha knew that [death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_sights#Observing_the_sights) is too painful and fearsome to consider - even if it did lead to cessation - so Buddhism gives us the possibility of an alternative path to liberation from suffering. In this lifetime. Without needing to rely on belief in a next one.

Comment: What's the point of such a colllosal effort if natural death leads to cessation of suffering?

Comment: Because ending suffering in this lifetime is better than the alternative of death.

Comment: The notion that the Buddha preached the Dhamma for 45 years and created a system of Sangha who have to follow 227+ vinaya rules and meditate for years with difficulty just to have enlightenment few  years in advance is comical at best. Why not use a painless method of suicide? :)

Comment: Please note that my critical questioning serves only to strengthen my faith, but to answer your question with another: why is it that most atheists/materialists don't commit suicide, having no belief in rebirth or afterlife? And further, why do [92%-95% of suicide attempts fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_attempt#Epidemiology)?

Comment: @avatarKorra it may be because of the fear of uncertainty even though they like to believe that it ends at death. Not willing to end experiencing of sensual pleasures etc.

Comment: yes if they had any real faith that it ends at death then there would be no fear to commit suicide; they'd all be doing it. They make the intellectual argument for it and yet, deep inside, no one really sees truth in it.

Comment: @avatarKorra I find talk of suicide kind of offensive and wrong. Firstly, plenty of people don't suicide: and the fact that they don't does not prove that they believe in rebirth nor that they believe in annihilation (so suicide is irrelevant to the argument). Second, it's considered very wrong to encourage people to kill themselves, e.g. by describing the advantages of death (e.g. saying, "If you kill yourself then dukkha will end for you") -- it may be considered similar to actually killing someone. So I wish people would stop talking like that, avoid making that kind of argument.

Comment: @ChrisW My intention here is to remove any doubt that suicide is a wrong, flawed thing. If we are confident it is, then why not discuss it openly rather than run away from it and let doubt remain in the minds of people who may be too afraid to talk about it. Please don't take the investigation of death here to mean arguing for it.

Comment: @avatarKorra Maybe you're confident but I've answered [several questions about suicide](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a254%20%5bsuicide%5d) on this site, and the fact that people ask such questions [is a bit worrying](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=suicide+is%3Aquestion). So I don't like seeing casually ask, "So why don't you commit suicide then, to end suffering?" even if you only mean it as a rhetorical question and didn't intend it as a serious suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why buddha teach rebirth?

Because highest goal of buddhism is to avoid rebirth.

In reality even buddha teach or doesn’t,
Rebirth mechanism is still there.

And it’s the origin of every suffer.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to create a second answer for this question, that's completely different to the first one.

Please also see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/34206/471).

## TL;DR

Denying rebirth-of-self view while clinging to self view is wrong view, because this is annihilationism and brings the unenlightened to hedonism.

Denying rebirth-of-self view after discarding self view is the noble right view. Rebirth without self view is simply the continuation of suffering and the continuation of the chain of conditioned processes. It's not about the rebirth of a specific person or being or self or consciousness.

Rebirth view can be used as skillful means ([upaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upaya)) to remove the habit of misconduct, cultivate virtue and generate the path to liberation. Rebirth view is the middle way and is the right view with effluents/ taints.

## Long answer

Denying rebirth-of-self, while clinging to self-view, appears to be wrong view. This is unskillful means because it directs the mind of the unenlightened towards hedonism and nihilism. This is also the view of annihilationism.

> And what is wrong view? 'There is nothing given, nothing offered,
> nothing sacrificed. There is no fruit or result of good or bad
> actions. There is no this world, **no next world**, no mother, no father,
> no spontaneously reborn beings; no contemplatives or brahmans who,
> faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the next
> after having directly known & realized it for themselves.' This is
> wrong view.
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

Holding on to the rebirth-of-self, while clinging to the fetter of self view, is a right view with effluents/ taints.

> "And what is the right view **with effluents**, siding with merit,
> resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
> what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
> There is this world & the next world. There is mother & father. There
> are spontaneously reborn beings; there are contemplatives & brahmans
> who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the
> next after having directly known & realized it for themselves.' This
> is the right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions.
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

Why is this the case? This is because siding with merit, one could use this as skillful means ([upaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upaya)), a helpful tool, to remove the habit of misconduct, cultivate virtue and generate the path to liberation.

The Buddha is the doctor ([Iti 100](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.4.100-112.than.html#iti-100)) who treats the illness which is suffering (*dukkha*). This is a medicine that he has prescribed.

> “And for the sake of what benefit should a woman or a man, a
> householder or one gone forth, often reflect thus: ‘I am the owner of
> my kamma, the heir of my kamma; I have kamma as my origin, kamma as my
> relative, kamma as my resort; I will be the heir of whatever kamma,
> good or bad, that I do’? People engage in misconduct by body, speech,
> and mind. **But when one often reflects upon this theme, such misconduct
> is either completely abandoned or diminished**. It is for the sake of
> this benefit that a woman or a man, a householder or one gone forth,
> should often reflect thus: ‘I am the owner of my kamma, the heir of my
> kamma; I have kamma as my origin, kamma as my relative, kamma as my
> resort; I will be the heir of whatever kamma, good or bad, that I do.’
> .....
>
> “This noble disciple reflects thus: ‘I am not the only one who is the
> owner of one’s kamma, the heir of one’s kamma; who has kamma as one’s
> origin, kamma as one’s relative, kamma as one’s resort; who will be
> the heir of whatever kamma, good or bad, that one does. All beings
> that come and go, that pass away and undergo rebirth, are owners of
> their kamma, heirs of their kamma; all have kamma as their origin,
> kamma as their relative, kamma as their resort; all will be heirs of
> whatever kamma, good or bad, that they do.’ **As he often reflects on
> this theme, the path is generated.** He pursues this path, develops it,
> and cultivates it. As he does so, the fetters are entirely abandoned
> and the underlying tendencies are uprooted.
> [AN 5.57](https://suttacentral.net/an5.57/en/bodhi)

Once self-view is discarded, rebirth-of-self view will also be discarded. This is the noble Right View.

> "And what is the right view that is noble, without effluents,
> transcendent, a factor of the path? The discernment, the faculty of
> discernment, the strength of discernment, analysis of qualities as a
> factor for awakening, the path factor of right view in one developing
> the noble path whose mind is noble, whose mind is without effluents,
> who is fully possessed of the noble path. This is the right view that
> is noble, without effluents, transcendent, a factor of the path.
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

How do we know that rebirth-of-self view will be discarded? This is the higher teaching for those who have understood anatta, as taught in [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi) and [SN 22.85](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.85/en/bodhi).

Rebirth without self view is simply the continuation of suffering and the continuation of the chain of conditioned processes. It's not about the rebirth of a specific person or being or self or consciousness.

> “Yes, friend,” he replied, and he went to the Blessed One, and after
> paying homage to him, sat down at one side. The Blessed One then asked
> him: “Sāti, is it true that the following pernicious view has arisen
> in you: ‘As I understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, it is
> this same consciousness that runs and wanders through the round of
> rebirths, not another’?”
>
> “Exactly so, venerable sir. As I understand the Dhamma taught by the
> Blessed One, it is this same consciousness that runs and wanders
> through the round of rebirths, not another.”
>
> “What is that consciousness, Sāti?”
>
> “Venerable sir, it is that which speaks and feels and experiences here
> and there the result of good and bad actions.”
>
> “Misguided man, to whom have you ever known me to teach the Dhamma in
> that way? Misguided man, have I not stated in many ways consciousness
> to be dependently arisen, since without a condition there is no
> origination of consciousness? But you, misguided man, have
> misrepresented us by your wrong grasp and injured yourself and stored
> up much demerit; for this will lead to your harm and suffering for a
> long time.”
> [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi)

> “But, friend, when the Tathagata is not apprehended by you as real and
> actual here in this very life, is it fitting for you to declare: ‘As I
> understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, a bhikkhu whose
> taints are destroyed is annihilated and perishes with the breakup of
> the body and does not exist after death’?”
>
> “Formerly, friend Sāriputta, when I was ignorant, I did hold that
> pernicious view, but now that I have heard this Dhamma teaching of the
> Venerable Sāriputta I have abandoned that pernicious view and have
> made the breakthrough to the Dhamma.”
>
> “If, friend Yamaka, they were to ask you: ‘Friend Yamaka, when a
> bhikkhu is an arahant, one whose taints are destroyed, what happens to
> him with the breakup of the body, after death?’—being asked thus, what
> would you answer?”
>
> “If they were to ask me this, friend, I would answer thus: ‘Friends,
> form is impermanent; what is impermanent is suffering; what is
> suffering has ceased and passed away. Feeling … Perception …
> Volitional formations … Consciousness is impermanent; what is
> impermanent is suffering; what is suffering has ceased and passed
> away.’ Being asked thus, friend, I would answer in such a way.”
> [SN 22.85](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.85/en/bodhi)

> Why now do you assume 'a being'?
> Mara, have you grasped a view?
> This is a heap of sheer constructions:
> Here no being is found.
>
> Just as, with an assemblage of parts,
> The word 'chariot' is used,
> So, when the aggregates are present,
> There's the convention 'a being.'
>
> It's only suffering that comes to be,
> Suffering that stands and falls away.
> Nothing but suffering comes to be,
> Nothing but suffering ceases.
> [SN 5.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn05/sn05.010.bodh.html)

> "Then, Bāhiya, you should train yourself thus: In reference to the
> seen, there will be only the seen. In reference to the heard, only the
> heard. In reference to the sensed, only the sensed. In reference to
> the cognized, only the cognized. That is how you should train
> yourself. When for you there will be only the seen in reference to the
> seen, only the heard in reference to the heard, only the sensed in
> reference to the sensed, only the cognized in reference to the
> cognized, then, Bāhiya, there is no you in connection with that. When
> there is no you in connection with that, there is no you there. When
> there is no you there, you are neither here nor yonder nor between the
> two. This, just this, is the end of stress (suffering)."
> [Ud 1.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.10.than.html)

I think this is excellent because it finally tells us what rebirth really is in Buddhism. It's not falsehood. It's not truth. It's just skillful means ([upaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upaya)), a helpful tool. A middle way between falsehood and truth.

Comment: what do you say if asked whether a stream-enterer exists after death?

Comment: @Letsbuddhism The answer to this question, from the perspective of ultimate truth comes from [Yamaka Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.085.than.html) and [Vajira Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn05/sn05.010.than.html). - "What? Do you assume a 'living being,' Mara?
Do you take a position? This is purely a pile of fabrications. Here no living being can be pinned down."

Comment: then i say, in as far as having grasped with wrong view something to be a stream-enterer then, is this stream-enterer said/held/seen to take another birth in particular?

Comment: @Letsbuddhism A stream enterer has discarded self-view. Which wrong view is grasped? A stream enterer is a person (puggala) as stated in Bhara Sutta (SN 22.22). But this is also a fabrication. The first noble truth says "there is suffering". It doesn't say "there is a sufferer".

Comment: i mean that it is said that a sotapanna won't take an 8th birth. It is said in regards to what is said to be a being, a being a concept that is conceived due to a grasping what the senses present with wrong view. Therein mind or body are misunderstood and taken to be personal and or eternal. This is the doctrine of self, in this doctrine of self one speaks of rebirth of a being. Having abandoned wrong view one can still entertain and understand the doctrine without believing it.

Comment: If they don’t penetrate so far, with the ending of three fetters, they’re a one-seeder. They will be reborn just one time in a human existence, then make an end of suffering.
If they don’t penetrate so far, with the ending of three fetters, they go from family to family. They will transmigrate between two or three families and then make an end of suffering.
If they don’t penetrate so far, with the ending of three fetters, they have at most seven rebirths. They will transmigrate at most seven times among gods and humans and then make an end of suffering.

Comment: obviously the answer as to whether a sotapanna is reborn is yes and that up to seven times and the answer as to whether sotapanna can be pinned down as a truth & reality in & by itself is a no. However there is that which can be grasped with wrong view to be a sotapanna and that will change as it persists until it is fully extinguished in no more than 7 births.

Comment: @Letsbuddhism Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think it's not a problem to say that a sotapanna exists after death in as far as they are held to transmigate for up to seven more times and that only Arahants in this exact sense abandon all modes of existence in as far as they become completely extinguished with no residue for a future. I like both of your answers.

Comment: also this then makes sense 'Having understood the unconditioned state,
Released in mind with the cord of being destroyed,
They have attained to the Dhamma-essence.
Delighting in the destruction (of craving),
Those stable ones have abandoned all being.'

Comment: @Letsbuddhism The idea of rebirth without self view is simply the continuation of suffering and the continuation of the chain of conditioned processes. It's not about the rebirth of a specific person or being or self or consciousness

Comment: This seems very wrong. I think your previous answer was better ;)

Comment: @YesheTenley The previous answer is tainted with self view.

Comment: This one too, but with more confusion as a spice :)

Comment: @YesheTenley At some point, we have to stop sneaking in the self through the back door.  ;-)

Comment: Who is this "we" you refer to? Do you and I not exist?

Comment: @YesheTenley That's Mara.

Comment: Was it Mara speaking to Ananda in MN 81? "Ānanda, you might think: ‘Surely the brahmin student Jotipāla must have been someone else at that time?’ But you should not see it like this. I myself was the student Jotipāla at that time.”

Comment: You've misunderstood Vajira and should put down that snake you are grasping.

Comment: @Ruben2020 by suffering therein what exactly do you mean? I am trying to make sure nothing slips by and it is close as it is but depends on what you mean by suffering, if you mean sankhara-dukkhata denoting anything other than the nibbana principle then i would agree with the expression

Comment: @Letsbuddhism Yes, that's right.

Comment: @YesheTenley I have added Bahiya Sutta (Ud 1.10). That should be very clear.

Comment: That is a wonderful sutta, but in no way denies the rebirth of persons. For such a mind unbound a 'person' does not even appear. What could there be to deny?

Comment: We are lucky, we are most fortunate to find in you, friend, a companion in the holy life who is so well-versed in both the meaning and the expression!

Answer (score 0):

Rebirth Concept was there in India[Early stages India called Dambadiwa] among Rishi's who meditated and achieved "Dyana" supreme mental states.  Actually,  Buddha taught us how to stop rebirth. This is the concept Lord Buddha understood from his Omniscience. Though the rebirth concept was there even "Rishi" did not have Supreme mundane wisdom to explain rebirth concept exactly.  They might have seen previous births in some extend where lord buddha seen rebirth to the eternity. That is why his wisdom called Omniscience.

Why do we wanted to avoid pain of Cancer? Because it causes whole life suffering. By knowing that we are taking precautionary measures to avoid cancer. If we found it earlier stages we completely remove it from the body. Furthermore, to avoid occuring cancer cells we do chemotherapy.

Similarly, Lord Buddha understood from his Omniscience that the creatures are sufferings from eternal journey of samsara within this 31 levels of the universe [4 Hells, 26 Divines and Earth].  Out of these 31 most of the creatures travelling through 4 hells only. Very similar to the cancer.

Giving this example he said. If someone takes a certain amount of soil from the earth on the nail tip of the thumb finger, that much creatures  will go to the divine worlds , the Brahma worlds  and  the human world,. Rest of the creatures equal to the earth's soil will go to hell. That is why Lord Buddha introduce  the hells  as creature's great house.

By knowing this great disaster with "Metta and Karuna" he wanted to stop creatures facing this agony while rescuing them.

Without convincing the reality of this samsara journey, the painful sorrowful agony one can face and going through, if he talk about the luxury life then no one wanted to attain Nibbana.  People love this lust life.

Lord Buddha in his Omniscience understood the way to overcome this dependent origination circle  by stopping the rebirth. That is where he introduce us four noble truth and the eightfold path.

Now your question was answered.  Without knowing the cause or the reason we cannot overcome the issue.  We need to stop occurrence to stop the result occurring due to that cause.

That is why causality was explained.

May Triple Gem Blessed You.

Answer (score -2):

The Buddha taught rebirth because it is something real that is related to the arising of suffering; namely, the re-arising of the delusion of "self" as a result of the emotions created by kamma (actions). Whenever the idea of "I" or "mine" arises as a result of an action, this is "rebirth".

Discerning an absence of rebirth in the mind is necessary to understand emptiness. Also, rebirth (kamma & results) is one example of causality.

A Buddhist doctrine that make sense without rebirth is the Three Characteristics. Seeing the Three Characteristics is unrelated to rebirth.

Knowing Nirvana is also unrelated to rebirth although, similar to Emptiness, knowing Nirvana coincides with knowing an absence of rebirth in the mind.

As for a rebirth as an "afterlife", this is an unknowable unproveable primitive superstition. Any claims there is a "Truth of Afterlife Rebirth" is obviously a lie or falsehood because there is no evidence for this belief. It is only a "belief" but not a "truth".

Comment: "obviously a lie or falsehood" is problematic and I think you should remove this. It is disparaging others and impolite and does not reflect patience for others understanding even if you think that "understanding" is a misunderstanding or confusion.

Comment: Thinking that all mental activities end at death is the unsubstantiated, unskillful, primitive, superstitious belief. :)

Comment: Read my answer.