# Why is a soul reincarnated, and the purpose of reincarnation?

Tags: consciousness, reincarnation, scripture, soul

> A soul from a previous generation is reincarnated in a later
> generation into a specific set of circumstances which are tailored to
> engineer a rectification of a previous sin

Are there instances in Buddhist scripture or history where there is a confirmation of the above statement as being typical, or being the purpose, of reincarnation?

Don't know if sin prefigures in Buddhist thought or has connections to reincarnation, but the source of the quote above is drawn from Judaism and Kabbalah's conceptualization of reincarnation, which they do relate to sin.

Answer (score 1):

There is no soul in Buddhism and it is not the same mind that persists going from one life to another.

It's as if one was to light a fire from another fire, the two fires are not technically the same fire but one is a cause & requisite condition for another and in that sense they are a linked and are in a sense "a fire".

The mental truths are such as feelings, thoughts, perception, things that aren't measured in mass. These are also with a cause, this or that mentality is linked to previous development and one's mentality does not become extinguished if there are causes for it's maintenance as fuel.

Buddha taught how to remove the causes for the arising of mentality and the truth & reality of it's cessation principle.

Comment: Does a reincarnated soul have memory of their past lives?

Comment: if the body (similar to candle wax) ceases, how can a flame pass to another flame?

Comment: Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1):

There's not an entity or being that gets reincarnated. That's a misunderstanding of reality and Buddhism.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism Stack Exchange. The system flagged this as a low quality answer. This answer is too short and doesn't contain enough details. Also, if possible, it is preferred to cite sources to support the answer. Did you intend it to be a [comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) under the question? If not, please see [this guide](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference with the Buddhist notion of reincarnation (lit. "re-enfleshment") is that the two incarnations do not share the same mind, nor does the same mind physically travel between physical bodies. There is no notion of "the soul" in Buddhism. Instead, there is "the mind," "the body," and "the life faculty."

"The soul" is a Judeo-Christian concept. Certainly, other cultures have things in them that resemble "the soul" (such as the "po and hum" of traditional Chinese religion, or the "Ka" of ancient Egyptian religion, etc.), but when we analyse these closely we will find that they don't line up identically to the Westerly notion of "a soul." Certainly, they are theories about a part of the impermanent human being that is, in fact, immortal and ageless, but these diverse theories are not all identical and not all describing "the same thing."

Instead of related to "sin (against God)," Buddhist rebirth/reincarnation (it's all the same words in Buddhism and Buddhism natively does not differentiate between "rebirth" and "reincarnation," those both being English-specific terms) is related to "karma," both the old karma which is a burden and the new karma which will propel further births.

Comment: So if the question is presenting the correcting of sin as the purpose for reincarnation to occur, Buddhism says no, this is not the reason for reincarnation, but that reincarnation has no purpose, it just happens passively and naturally?

Comment: It happens according to karma, AFAIK.

Comment: What are some karmic circumstances for reincarnation to occur?

Comment: Taṁ jīvaṁ taṁ sarīranti vā, bhikkhu, diṭṭhiyā sati brahmacariyavāso na hoti. If you have the view that the soul (jiva) and the body are different things, there is no living of the spiritual life. https://suttacentral.net/sn12.35/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false

Comment: What are some karmic circumstances for reincarnation to occur?

Comment: i am a bit perplexed by this statement. If there is rebirth, then there has to be something that goes from body to body. Otherwise, this is an entirely different being. I don't see why people here frequently insists that "you don't reincarnate". In my view, this is not a useful nor accurate statement. In fact there are people who remember their past lives pretty well and feel emotions / ideas of their past selves

Comment: It is the Buddha who says that the notion that one particular consciousness goes from body to body is a mistaken view. See his dialogue with Sati the Fisherman's Son.

Answer (score -1):

There are some suttas providing info on this like [MN 135](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than.html) (quoted below), [MN 136](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.136.than.html) and [AN 4.85](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.085.than.html).

However, as mentioned in other answers, there is rebirth in the suttas, but no reincarnation. And certainly there is no soul or impermanent self. According to [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi), there is no continuity of the same consciousness throughout one or more lives.

Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45337/471) for an explanation.

Rebirth is only the continuation of chained conditioned processes and the continuation of suffering. We don't assign any identity or self or soul to this rebirth.

However, the rebirth-of-self view is also used as skillful means or as a tool to get unenlightened persons with self view, to instill the mindset of being ashamed of doing evil (*hiri*) and having a fear of doing evil (*otappa*). This is found in [AN 5.57](https://suttacentral.net/an5.57/en/bodhi) and in line with the Right View with effluents or taints in [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html).

> The Blessed One said: "There is the case, student, where a woman or
> man is a killer of living beings, brutal, bloody-handed, given to
> killing & slaying, showing no mercy to living beings. Through having
> adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the body, after
> death, he/she reappears in the plane of deprivation, the bad
> destination, the lower realms, hell. If, on the break-up of the body,
> after death — instead of reappearing in the plane of deprivation, the
> bad destination, the lower realms, hell — he/she comes to the human
> state, then he/she is short-lived wherever reborn. This is the way
> leading to a short life: to be a killer of living beings, brutal,
> bloody-handed, given to killing & slaying, showing no mercy to living
> beings.
>
> "But then there is the case where a woman or man, having abandoned the
> killing of living beings, abstains from killing living beings, and
> dwells with the rod laid down, the knife laid down, scrupulous,
> merciful, & sympathetic for the welfare of all living beings. Through
> having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the
> body, after death, he/she reappears in a good destination, in the
> heavenly world. If, on the break-up of the body, after death — instead
> of reappearing in a good destination, in the heavenly world — he/she
> comes to the human state, then he/she is long-lived wherever reborn.
> This is the way leading to a long life: to have abandoned the killing
> of living beings, to abstain from killing living beings, to dwell with
> one's rod laid down, one's knife laid down, scrupulous, merciful, &
> sympathetic for the welfare of all living beings.
>
> "There is the case where a woman or man is one who harms beings with
> his/her fists, with clods, with sticks, or with knives. Through having
> adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the body, after
> death, he/she reappears in the plane of deprivation... If instead
> he/she comes to the human state, then he/she is sickly wherever
> reborn. This is the way leading to sickliness: to be one who harms
> beings with one's fists, with clods, with sticks, or with knives.
>
> "But then there is the case where a woman or man is not one who harms
> beings with his/her fists, with clods, with sticks, or with knives.
> Through having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of
> the body, after death, he/she reappears in a good destination... If
> instead he/she comes to the human state, then he/she is healthy
> wherever reborn. This is the way leading to health: not to be one who
> harms beings with one's fists, with clods, with sticks, or with
> knives.
>
> "There is the case, where a woman or man is ill-tempered & easily
> upset; even when lightly criticized, he/she grows offended, provoked,
> malicious, & resentful; shows annoyance, aversion, & bitterness.
> Through having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of
> the body, after death, he/she reappears in the plane of deprivation...
> If instead he/she comes to the human state, then he/she is ugly
> wherever reborn. This is the way leading to ugliness: to be
> ill-tempered & easily upset; even when lightly criticized, to grow
> offended, provoked, malicious, & resentful; to show annoyance,
> aversion, & bitterness.
>
> "But then there is the case where a woman or man is not ill-tempered
> or easily upset; even when heavily criticized, he/she doesn't grow
> offended, provoked, malicious, or resentful; doesn't show annoyance,
> aversion, or bitterness. Through having adopted & carried out such
> actions, on the break-up of the body, after death, he/she reappears in
> a good destination... If instead he/she comes to the human state, then
> he/she is beautiful wherever reborn. This is the way leading to
> beauty: not to be ill-tempered or easily upset; even when heavily
> criticized, not to be offended, provoked, malicious, or resentful; nor
> to show annoyance, aversion, & bitterness.
>
> "There is the case where a woman or man is envious. He/she envies,
> begrudges, & broods about others' gains, honor, respect, reverence,
> salutations, & veneration. Through having adopted & carried out such
> actions, on the break-up of the body, after death, he/she reappears in
> the plane of deprivation... If instead he/she comes to the human
> state, then he/she is not influential wherever reborn. This is the way
> leading to not being influential: to be envious, to envy, begrudge, &
> brood about others' gains, honor, respect, reverence, salutations, &
> veneration.
> [MN 135](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than.html)