# Various types of death

Tags: theravada, rebirth, death

In [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/10113/471), Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu wrote about various types of death (quoted below).

1. Where can I find references to and more info on the various types of death that is mentioned - khaṇika-maraṇa, sammuti-maraṇa and samuccheda-maraṇa? It can be from the Pali Canon or other sources.
2. Are there also other types of death? According to [this source](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=u23XDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA23&ots=LImVtYLwV5&dq=sammuti-mara%E1%B9%87a&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=sammuti-mara%E1%B9%87a&f=false), there is also paramattha-maraṇa (ultimate death).
3. Does sammuti-maraṇa refer to physical death? [This source](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=u23XDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA23&ots=LImVtYLwV5&dq=sammuti-mara%E1%B9%87a&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=sammuti-mara%E1%B9%87a&f=false) calls it "conventional death".

Any other additional info or explanation is welcomed.

> The Buddha never, afaik, used a term that could be translated as
>   "rebirth". In fact, the idea of anything being reborn goes against
>   orthodox early Buddhist teachings. Throughout the Buddha's teachings,
>   it is made clear that at the breakup of the body there is birth, not
>   rebirth - as in birth of new things, not the return of anything old.
>
> ... In this
>   life, there is what is called *khaṇika-maraṇa* - death of a moment.
>   Each momentary experience is born and dies, never to arise again. At
>   the moment of conceptual death (*sammuti-maraṇa*), this process of
>   momentary birth and death continues unimpeded unless one has
>   experienced "death by cutting off" (*samuccheda-maraṇa*) - i.e. of the
>   defilements (q.v. Vism VIII.167) - in which case there is no further
>   arising.
>
> To put it succinctly, physical death isn't even real according to
>   early Buddhism; it is a concept based on the artificial construct of a
>   "being" who is "born".
>
> (And in [this comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10067/#comment14637_10113):) New birth is related to old birth, but nothing
>   is ever reborn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three types of death are commonly referred to by the Theravada commentaries (e.g. AN-a 1.18 aparāccharāsaṅghātavaggavaṇṇanā). A description of them is found in the Vibhaṅga commentary:

> Tattha ‘khaṇikamaraṇaṃ’ nāma pavatte rūpārūpadhammānaṃ bhedo. ‘Tisso mato, phusso mato’ti idaṃ ‘sammutimaraṇaṃ’ nāma. Khīṇāsavassa appaṭisandhikā kālakiriyā ‘samucchedamaraṇaṃ’ nāma.

I wouldn't be surprised if other traditions talked about other types of death, but these are the types of death recognized by the orthodox Theravada commentaries.

In the quote above, *sammutimaraṇa* refers to when we say "Tissa died." or "Phussa died." (Tissa and Phussa are just common Pali names).

Comment: Welcome back, Bhante!