# Talking to dead loved ones

Tags: death, marriage, life-after-death

Could talking with dead loved ones be in line with the proper practice of the Buddha? If proper practice permits talking to dead loved ones, then what is the proper way to talk to dead loved ones and/or the improper way to talk to dead loved ones?

Comment: how do you talk to loved dead ones?  i want to as well...

Comment: How can you talk to a bunch of phenomena ie. the 5 Aggregates that's constantly arising and perishing??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's the "practice of the Buddha" -- though there are suttas in which he tells the audience, the state in which a deceased person is [re]born. You might infer something about the proper practice of the Buddha, from the behaviour of his disciples at the end of the Parinibbana sutta.

However perhaps something like it is a "Buddhist practice", for some forms of Buddhism -- I don't know details (haven't experienced it) but see for example, [Wikipedia: Ghost festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Festival), and its links to various "related Buddhist traditions" in other countries.

I suppose the "proper" way is with metta -- "May you be well".

And, following the Kimattha sutta, "without remorse".

In my personal experience it has been, when I'm dreaming. And the "reality" of those dreams, in contrast to "reality" when awake, had me think twice about what "reality" is: for example how much of it, including perception of the loved one, is mind-made.

See also [Various types of death](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/30425/254)

Comment: You can talk directly to someone not in the room with metta like everyone in the world but a dead loved one, are they supposed to be somewhere in samsara? Are there accounts of ghosts that were related to a living person?

Comment: You're asking about "somewhere" but I can't say "where" my wife is now -- because "where" generally seems to have a physical meaning, which maybe no longer applies -- she expected to be reborn and is I think still with me as a karmic imprint, result of her kamma and mine. I know exceedingly little of ghosts from the Pali canon, I do suspect there's doctrine about it in Tibetan Buddhism. Perhaps "ghosts" aren't described as benevolent, on the other hand maybe "tulkus" are, so.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating with a Departed Loved One

According to Buddhism, we are reborn time and again based on our karma. This means that immediately after death, we are sent to a place determined by our own actions. This cycle continues until an individual attains enlightenment.

We cannot predict with absolute certainty where we will be reborn after death. If an individual is reborn as a ghost or God, they may retain some memories from their past life. However, if they are reborn as a human or animal, they usually don’t have any recollection of their past life. Those in hell may also be aware of their past life and actions.

Buddhism teaches us that death is inevitable for all, so we should avoid forming overly strong attachments to anyone. The cycle of life, or Samsara, is very long and we may have been related to each other in some past life. Bond, desire,.. cause to rebirth.

You may be able to communicate with your departed loved ones, especially if they have been reborn as ghosts or gods (although this doesn’t always work). Gods usually don’t want to continue their past relationships with our world as they exist in a different time dimension and lead luxurious lives.
This communication can have positive or negative effects on you. (I think more negative)
There is also possibility for be together life after life some time even until end of samsara (according to their karma and strong wish).

It’s beneficial to perform positive karma when someone passes away and wish something like, “I am doing good deeds and I hope that my actions contribute to the well-being of my departed loved one.” If the departed one is reborn in a realm where they can receive another person’s karma (some ghost and God realms), they will receive it.